# openssl verify doesn't detect certificate tampering

Tags: ssl, openssl, cryptography, certificate

I've got two certificates - root and the second one signed by root. 
Now I've tampered the second certificate  -  changed **Subject Public Key Info (Modulus)** section. When I verify it:

> openssl verify -verbose -CAfile root-ca.crt signing-ca_damaged.crt

It prints "OK" and no error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you tamper with that certificate?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out: I should have modify base64-encoded data in the end of the file, not it's text representation.